# R maps plotting longitude and latitude points

Tags: r, maps, latitude-longitude

I have a map of the USA and a list of long, lat that I want to plot.  Once I get this working, I also want to switch over to the "world" map.  The map is generated, but no points appear on the map.  The first line of the TSV file contains this header:

```
LONG{tab}LAT
```

R appears to be reading in the 'traffic' table OK.  What am I doing wrong?

```
library("maps")

traffic = read.table("C:/temp/traffic_10.40.tsv", header=T, sep="\t")
png(filename="C:/temp/usa.png", width=850, height=600, bg="white")
map('state', plot = TRUE, fill = FALSE, col = palette())
title("Destinations")
points(x=traffic$LONG,y=traffic$LAT,col='red',cex=0.75)
dev.off()
```

**EDIT**

```
> dput(traffic)
structure(list(LONG = c(47.6218, 32.7942, 34.1121, 40.0068, 47.6218,
33.9553, 33.7629, 40.0068, 39.05, 38.1075, 33.7629, 32.769, 37.3857,
29.4576, 34.1674, 38.8147, 32.7942, 31.1429, 40.3254, 30.3059,
38.2248, 47.6218, 33.9553, 38.1075, 27.1943, 29.4576, 30.5175,
38.5668, 42.6657, 40.2982, 32.7539, 40.6698, 47.6742, 32.7942,
47.6218, 35.8219), LAT = c(-122.35, -96.7653, -118.411, -75.1347,
-122.35, -83.3937, -84.4226, -75.1347, -77.4833, -122.264, -84.4226,
-96.5998, -122.026, -98.5054, -84.8014, -77.0647, -96.7653, -81.471,
-78.9195, -97.7505, -85.7412, -122.35, -83.3937, -122.264, -80.2432,
-98.5054, -97.6721, -121.467, -73.799, -111.698, -97.3363, -73.9438,
-122.115, -96.7653, -122.35, -78.6588)), .Names = c("LONG", "LAT"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Also, I am a R newbie and have tried finding this on google with limited success because I am not sure what to search for exactly.

Comment: Hard to say without access to your data. Any way to post the .tsv or png online?

Comment: or ... post the data online? the easiest way is to copy and paste the results of `dput(traffic)`; or if it a big data set, try `dput(traffic[1:10,]`

Comment: Your map of the USA appears to be a PNG file. This has no geographical coordinates associated to it, so there's no way of knowing where a given lat-long point is. It might even be in a funny projection, or Alaska could be tucked down off the coast of California for compactness, and Hawaii in the Gulf. You need a proper georeferenced raster file, or knowledge of the projection and coordinates of the PNG.

Comment: It might be worth reposting/moving the post over to http://gis.stackexchange.com/ There are a few `R` and `mapping` over questions there.

Comment: @Spacedman: even if I comment out the png command or run it interactively, I still do not get any points on the map.

Comment: @jftuga, thanks for asking this question. I am new to spatial statistics and was trying for hours to generate a map with plotted points yesterday. Your example is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in your data set rather than your later code.

The first point has one co-ordinate `47.6218` and the other `-122.35`.  [Latitudes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) cannot be outside the range `[-90,90]` degrees so the [longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) must be `-122.35` and  latitude `47.6218`, the opposite of your data set.  [This is slightly north of the Seattle Space needle](http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=47.6218,-122.35&z=19)

`x` (horizontal) is traditionally longitude or easting; `y` (vertical) is traditionally latitude or northing

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I adjusted my code (the right way) and it is running great!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [googleVis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/index.html) for this. You could plot out your points Google-Maps style.

Comment: I need to output to PNG so I don't think this would help.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I swapped $LAT and $LONG.  Now it works perfectly.

```
points(x=traffic$LAT,y=traffic$LONG,col='red',cex=0.75)
```